# trace32 data.load.elf error "verify error at address NSX:0x8000"

Tags: embedded, trace32, lauterbach

This is my first time using Trace32 and I'm trying to flash a simple C program on arm target when I try to execute this command (to my knowledge this command will flash the target but not sure?).

```
d.load.elf image.axf /Verify /ComPare
```

I get the following error:

> verify error at address NSX:0x8000

I used the following commands to compile and link the code :

```
armclang --target=aarch64-arm-none-eabi hellofunc.c hellomake.c -g -fdata- 
sections -ffunction-sections -c

armlink --entry=0x8594 hellofunc.o hellomake.o --output=image.axf
```

How can I flash the code and debug it? execute each instruction step by step

Thank you

Comment: This is an RTFM question, then failing that a [Lauterbach Technical Support](https://www.lauterbach.com/frames.html?home.html) question.

Comment: What kind of memory do you have (and/or expect) at memory address NS:0x8000? Is you MMU already configured when you trying to write to that memory?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot program flash memory if it is already programmed - it must first be erased.  Refer to page 93 of the [Trace32 documentation](http://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/general_ref_d.pdf). Moreover attempting to `compare` the flash memory with the file *before* you have programmed it will always fail!

You need to have erased the flash *and* also to have enabled the flash for programming.  For example:

```
FLASH.Erase ALL
FLASH.Program ALL
Data.load.elf image.axf /Verify
FLASH.Program off
```

Note that Erase.ALL may be inappropriate if you have other data or perhaps a bootloader in flash besides the code to be programmed/debugged.

Comment: i tried that but i get the same error
and i don't have bootloader  it is a very simple test program, just a couple of variable

Comment: @EslamGamal I have modified the answer after reading the documentation.  Note I have never used this tool, only read the documentation... you could do that!  The point about bootloader/data is to make the answer generic and useful to other readers, and because the information was not included in your question.  Also the commands are an _example_, to be adapted to your target as necessary.

Comment: The FLASH commands mentioned by Clifford are an excellent choices for programming NOR-flash or Onchip-flash. However it looks like that the questioner Eslam Gamal is using an ARMv8 processor. Those are usually booting from serial memories like SPI, NAND, I2C or eMMC flashes and are programmed using the FLASHFILE commands.

Comment: @Holger Well spotted.  As I said "for example" and RTFM.  I cannot help if essential information is witheld.

Comment: @Holger 
what kind of essential information do you want?

Comment: @EslamGamal : Your question provides no information about your target, its memory architecture and technology or how it boots.  The Trace32 can accommodate a wide variety of combinations, and the necessary procedure will be target specific.  From your question and the error message, I had assumed a memory-mapped flash with your image starting at base 0x8000 - that may not be the case, in which case your programming procedure will not work, but it is not possible to advise what will work.  If you are using a COTS board, the simplest thing to do is specify what it is.

Comment: @EslamGamal : For starters: Which CPU have you selected in the SYStem.state window? What kind of memory do you expect at 0x8000 (SRAM, DRAM, NOR-Flash,...)? Is the MMU enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use load option `/ComPare` if you actually want to program your memory.

Option /ComPare means: Do not load any code. Instead read the memory (at the location where the ELF would be loaded) and compare the memory content with the ELF file.

If you want to load your application to a writeable memory and verify the successful loading, please do the following:

```
Data.LOAD.Elf image.axf
Data.LOAD.Elf image.axf /ComPare
```

or

```
Data.LOAD.Elf image.axf
Data.LOAD.Elf image.axf /DIFF
IF FOUND()
( 
    PRINT %ERROR "Faild to load application image.axf at address " TRACK.ADDRESS() 
)
```

By the way: I won't call such a load of an application "flashing". In my opinion "flashing" is about programming non-volatile memory.

Comment: any ideas on why it has a problem with address NSX:0x8000?
i tried your method but i still get the same error

Comment: Open the window `Data.dump NSX:0x8000` and try to modify the value at that memory location. If this is not possible, the memory seem to be not writeable at that location in your current configuration. Which would bring us back to the question: What kind of memory do you expect there?